# A problem on stability of carbanion

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Determine the most stable of the two carbanions.
I found second one as more stable because of inductive effect. But the given answee is first one.

Comment: Do you mean carbocation or carbanion?

Answer (score -1):

Resonance is always a dominating factor over inductive effect. In the first option there is a d-orbital resonance of chlorine atom. The d-orbital of chlorine atom aligns itself parallel to the overlapped p-orbitals of the pi-bond and the p-orbital of the negative charge. Clearly, they are conjugated. Though resonance involving d-orbitals and p- orbitals are weak as compared to resonance involving all p-orbitals, this effect will still dominate over the inductive effect of fluorine. As fluorine does not have d-orbitals, it won't show any d-orbital resonance.